# Programmatically create window in Chrome that can be integrated into existing browser window

Tags: javascript, google-chrome, chromium

I can create a window using the `window.open` method, however the user is not able to drag the newly created window and integrate it (attach) in an existing **Chrome** browser window.  It is as if Chrome treats windows created via the `window.open` method as being of a different type and disallows attaching of these to standard browser windows.

`window.open` works correctly under Firefox.  Is there a workaround for Chrome?

EDIT: fiddle [here](https://jsfiddle.net/94sLtw09/).

Comment: Interesting. It also works with IE11.